# Using a class (or instance) property inside of another classes initilizer in swift

Tags: swift, class, sprite-kit, initialization, instantiation

I'm relatively new to Swift, and I wanted to know if there was a way to reference a class's property inside of a separate class initializer? For example: if I have a class `Person` with the property `position`, is there a way to initialize a `Pants` class such that its `position` is the same as `Person`'s? Here's my code:

```
    class Pants:SKSpriteNode{
        init(){

            let pants = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Sprites/pants.jpg")

            pants.setScale(0.5)

            super.init(texture: pants, color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: pants.size())

            //self.position.x = aPerson.position.x + (aPerson.size.width / 2)
            //self.position.y = aPerson.position.y - (aPerson.size.height * 0.04)
            self.position = Person.getPos()//CGPoint(x: 200,y: 200)
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
    }

}
```

At first I tried referencing `aPerson` which is an instance of `Person` but I received the error: `Instance member aPerson cannot be used on type GameScene`. I think understand why it doesn't make much sense to reference an instance in this case- as the instance may not exist by the time of reference? But I don't really know what this error message means- any clarification would be great. I then thought to use a `static` getter method within the `Person` class that just returned it's position property. This also doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions would be awesome!

Comment: It doesn't seem to make much sense for a `Person` *class* to have a position - instances of that class, individual people, have positions.

Comment: @paulgriffiths That actually makes sense- any suggestions on how to implement that? When I tried I received the error: `Instance member aPerson cannot be used on type GameScene`?

Comment: `Pants` needs access to an instance of `Person`, if you want to access instance attributes. You can either pass one to the initializer, or you can create one in the initializer, depending on what makes sense for your application.

Comment: Also, you ought to post the code for your `Person` class, too, to get a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to add a parameter to your initializer (as suggested by Paul Griffiths in a comment above):

```
class Pants: SKSpriteNode {
    init(aPerson: Person) {
        let pants = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Sprites/pants.jpg")
        pants.setScale(0.5)

        super.init(texture: pants, color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: pants.size())

        self.position.x = aPerson.position.x + (aPerson.size.width / 2)
        self.position.y = aPerson.position.y - (aPerson.size.height * 0.04)
        self.position = aPerson.getPos()//CGPoint(x: 200,y: 200)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Then wherever you want to create a `Pants` instance, you must pass a person:

```
let somePerson = Person()
let pants = Pants(aPerson: somePerson)
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume Pants are worn by Person?  so instead,  work relative, not absolute.

Make Pants a child node of person,  then all you need to worry about is the distance from the center of Person,  to the Pant line.  If this will always be a constant number (Like 10 pixels below center)  then hard code it.  If the Pant line changes,  then pass in the pant line like @Santa Claus suggests

====Assume some code here please======

```
person.pantline = -10;
person.addChild(Pants(pantline:person.pantline))
```

=====================================

```
class Pants: SKSpriteNode {
    convenience init(pantline: Int) {

        self.init(imageNamed: "Sprites/pants.jpg")
        self.setScale(0.5) //Why?

        self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5,1)
        self.position.y = pantline
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder:aDecoder)
    } 
    override init (texture: SKTexture, color: UIColor, size: CGSize)
    {
        super.init(texture: texture, color: color, size: size)
    }
```

}